# Sublime Text 2 code snippet

Tags: sublimetext

I just started using Sublime Text 2 yesterday and I'm liking it a lot. However, I am trying to set up a code snippet that I would use all the time. The problem is that the editor isn't recognizing it at all. I saved it in my Packages/User folder. The snippet is below:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[echo "<pre>".print_r(${0:var},true)."</pre>";]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>pre</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>print r with pre tags</description>
</snippet>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure it is saved with a `.sublime-snippet` extension.  Your snippet will only expand when the scope is php.  So it has to be in php tags even if it's in a php file.

Comment: Awesome, that was it, I didn't save it with that extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a snippet make sure you escape the `$` if needed since the `$` sign is used as a pointer.